# Reading from file using delimiter to find largest and smallest, gets Integers max/min not the numbers from file

Tags: java, while-loop, io

I´m trying to find the largest and smallest number from a textfile and has looked on other examples on stackowerflow.

But when I try I ends upp with Integer max and min value, not values from the file.
Since the numbers in the files are supposed to have semicolon to seperate them, I have tried to use delimiter.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
public class LargestAndSmallest
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
        {
            File file = new File("src/Number.txt");
            if (!file.exists())
            {
                System.out.println("File not found.");
                System.exit(0);
            }

            Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("src/Number.txt"));

            System.out.println("Writes out numbers from the file so the user can se them");     
            System.out.println(sc.nextLine());              

            sc.useDelimiter(";");

            int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;                              
            int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;                              

            while (sc.hasNextInt())                       
            {
                int currentNumber  = sc.nextInt();      

                if ( currentNumber  > max)                               
                {
                    max = currentNumber ;                                
                }

                if ( currentNumber  < min)                               
                {
                    min = currentNumber ;                                
                }
            }

            sc.close();                                      

            System.out.println("Smallest number: " +min);       
            System.out.println("Largest number: " +max);      
        }
    }
```

Comment: the code already read the input (to show to user), so the next attempt to read data will find nothing more to read - I recommend printing each number after reading it / or use a new `Scanner` based on the read line (BTW no need to create two instances of `File`)

Comment: Thank you very @user16320675, now I got it to work. Does it work the same if I would like to try it with floating numbers, but changing int to double?

Comment: @user16320675 I tried and failed, but then I changed from . to , for the numbers in the txt and got it to work. I think I have read that, that depeends on what language it is on the operating system.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.io.File;
 public class LargestAndSmallest
 { public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
  {
      File file = new File("src/Number.txt");
      if (!file.exists())
      {
          System.out.println("File not found.");
          System.exit(0);
      }

      Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("src/Number.txt"));

      sc.useDelimiter(";");
      System.out.println("Writes out numbers from the file so the user see");     
     
     int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;                              
     int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;            
             
     
     while (sc.hasNextInt())                       
     {
         

         int currentNumber  = sc.nextInt();      
         System.out.println(currentNumber);
         if ( currentNumber  > max)                               
         {
             max = currentNumber ;                                
         }

         if ( currentNumber  < min)                               
         {
             min = currentNumber ;                                
         }
         
         
     }
     sc.close();
                                        

     System.out.println("Smallest number: " +min);       
     System.out.println("Largest number: " +max);      
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Coming to your question remove this line `System.out.println(sc.nextLine());` 
as doing this you are making your cursor move in the next line of the file which is null so your values are getting initialize with

```
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;                              
int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

your while loop is not executing as sc is null you already move your cursor to null while doing `System.out.println(sc.nextLine());`

visit [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scanner-nextline-method-in-java-with-examples/) for more explanation

Try This Code for better optimization;-

Time Complexity -; **O(n log(n))**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LargestAndSmallest{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException {

        File file = new File("src/Number.txt");
        if (!file.exists()) {
            System.out.println("File not found.");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("src/Number.txt"));

        System.out.println("Writes out numbers from the file so the user can se them");

        int[] arr = Arrays.stream(sc.nextLine().trim().split(";")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
        Arrays.sort(arr);
        int max = arr[arr.length - 1];
        int min = arr[0];


        sc.close();

        System.out.println("Smallest number: " + min);
        System.out.println("Largest number: " + max);
    }

}
```